# Cyrillic and classicthesis: Clash error

Tags: classicthesis, cyrillic

I want to add a pair of lines in Russian to some file, which I'm writing with `classicthesis`. I tried adding cyrillic alphabet with the packages described just bellow, and had still no problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

English text and 
\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
русский текст
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

But when I add the lines that allow me to write in cyrillic to a working example written with `classicthesis`, I get `Option clash for package inputenc.\usepackage` and `Option clash for package babel` upon compiling the following:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,
                ngerman,american,
                ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble} 
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} 

English text and 
\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
русский текст
\end{otherlanguage*}}
\end{document}
```

Any hint?

Comment: Is that bunch of options to `\documentclass` relevant for your problem? If not, it'd be good if you removed that to make your code more minimal.

Comment: In the most recent versions of `classicthesis` the `classicthesis-preamble` package has been removed. If I load `\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis}` instead and move `\part{...}` *after* `\ctparttext{...}` (where it belongs) the document compiles.

Comment: well, @doncherry, since I don't know what is really giving me problems, they all are necesary, I guess. I began to write a year ago, and I need these options. @egreg I need `classicthesis-preamble` as well, in order to load my options (I know that in recent versions it has been replaced by some `.tex` file). I'll reedit as you suggested.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: That's beside the point. The question is whether your problem, i.e. the two option clash errors persist if you don't use these options; and as far as I can see, that is the case. Hence, you should remove these options from the MWE you provide here. One of our supreme goals for questions at tex.sx is to formulate problems in a way as abstract as possible, in order to make the problems and solutions applicable to as many users as possible. In other words, your specific application for the solution to be found here is not of interest.

Comment: I see. Ok, I'll make the code minimal...

Comment: @JorgeCampos It's *impossible* to answer without knowing what you have in `classicthesis-preamble`. Of course, `\selectlanguage{american}` is wrong, as you don't specify `american` but `english` in the options to `babel`.

Comment: I see @egreg. I'll spend some time in the meta.tex.

Comment: @egreg: `american` is a global option though?

Comment: @doncherry Oh! Didn't notice. Bad placement anyway: language options should be all global or all local.

Comment: @egreg: Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `classicthesis-preamble.sty` is similar to the file

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/latex/classicthesis/classicthesis-config.tex
```

that's included in the most recent distributions of ClassicThesis, then you have several problems.

The file calls

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{latin9}{inputenc} % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
 \usepackage{inputenc}
```

(which is a very peculiar way to proceed, since `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}` would do the same).

and so if you use it (or `classicthesis-preamble.sty` that should have the same line) you *can't* specify another input encoding after having loaded it.

So the solution is: *don't* load `classicthesis-preamble`. Having it was a mistake since the start of the ClassicThesis project. Now the distribution proposes the file I pointed to, but it's again an error to include it "as is": it must be tailored to your needs.

The same problem happens also with `babel`; you might solve this one by specifying `russian,english` among the global options, but the safest solution is to rip off the call of `babel` from the auxiliary `classicthesis-preamble` package.

Don't use `\selectlanguage{american}`: the last language loaded by `babel` is the default one; moreover you have `english` in the options (which is equivalent to `american` but you should always use the same name throughout a document).